# No display on desktop monitor

Tags: windows, graphics-card

I have a desktop. I turned it on this morning , I saw the bootscreen of windows 7 but it stopped just before I see the butterfly animation. Its just the starting windows text that I saw.
I turned it off then on again. But this time, there was no display.
Tried plugging the monitor to my laptop and it worked.
What I want to do now is to make sure that this is really a video card problem before I try to buy a new one.
What other tests could I perform to make sure that this is indeed a video card problem.

Comment: how do you know its not an OS issue?

Comment: cheack your Loose memory and graphics cards. and replay it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Plug a different monitor into your PC, see if that works.
2. If that doesn't work then take the video card out and put it in a different, working PC.

   - If you don't have another PC lying around, then you could try replacing the video card with an older one if you have one of those.
3. Check everything is seated properly. PCI cards especially have a tendency to sometimes come a little loose

Answer (score 1):

Try booting off a basic livecd of some sort - if the system boots fully, you know its not an OS issue. If its an OS issue, you may need to repair or reinstall windows.

Also, does the bios screen show in the display? Have you tried checking the seating of the graphics card?